# Managing C++ Dependencies over Multiple Projects

Tags: c++, deployment, dependencies, libraries

Presently, I am working in a repository which contains several projects. I inherited this repository, so its architecture is not my design. Each project depends upon some source files which are the same throughout. Right now, my quick and dirty solution is just to continually update the files in each project subdirectory through *shudder* copy-pasta. What might be a better way to manage these dependencies without duplicating source files? As an added note, creating libraries to be stored in my user path would not be a viable option. This would make running unit tests and ensuring up-to-date functionality across all projects much easier. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Use static libraries? Just use *one* instance of the common files and compile them in the various projects, adjusting paths as needed? Whatever you do, **don't duplicate code** it's a maintenance hell.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the perfect job for Maven. If you're working with C++ you'll need to use a plugin for native code compilation support. Have a look into this:

http://duns.github.io/maven-nar-plugin/

Comment: Maven would be wonderful, had I that flexibility. Unfortunately, I'm restricted to using pure, out-of-the-box Unix tools. I will definitely keep this plugin in mind for other projects though.

Answer (score 1):

Don't duplicate the common source files for each project. Instead place them in a folder called CommonSrc and then use 'add existing…' to include the sources into each project.

Either that, or compile the common sources to a library and then statically or dynamically link to that.

Comment: Static linking will probably be the route I take.